# NavigationBar Puzzle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

I have 2 Views. The first view is superview having a navigationBar on the top. On my first View there is one button having this method:

```
-(IBAction)openView:(id)sender{


[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];

view1 = [[ImageView alloc] init];
view1.largeImageDataTwo = self.aNewsInfo.largeImageData;
view1.titleTwo = self.aNewsInfo.title;

[self.view addSubview:view1.view];}
```

This action opens the view1 without having navigation-bar on the top. (as i want)

and on this particular page (View1) i'm having another button which using this method

```
-(IBAction)back:(id)sender{
[d1.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
[self.view removeFromSuperview];}
```

this method returns me to my 1st view(d1) but this time when I returned my 1st View is without the navigationBar but I want navigation bar back on this 1st View when I returned from the 2nd View.

How can I do this? How can I get navigationBar back on 1st View when returned from the Second View?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your first view, in your `viewWillAppear:` method, try calling `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO]`.

In your second view, after you call `removeFromSuperview`, you *might* have to call `[d1 viewWillAppear:YES]`. I am not sure if that is considered "best practice", but you might need to force it like this because `removeFromSuperview` may not call the super view's `viewWillAppear:` method automatically (like some other methods that change the view hierarchy.)